# Image in Facebook share dialog is cropped the first time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a custom open graph story that allows the user to share something that they created on my site (each creation is a unique URL). I've gotten Facebook to crawl the unique URLs properly, but when the share dialog comes up, the image is cropped into a square format. If I close the share dialog and reopen it, the image is then the full sized image that is in the og:image tag.

Is there a way for me to get the full sized image the first time the share dialog opens? Many thanks.